# I've written a code to check if a number is prime, but doesnt work

Tags: python, primes

My code is

```
import math
def pr(x):
    i = range(2,int(math.sqrt(x)+2))
    for n in i:
        if x%n == 0:
            return('Not prime')
        else:
            return('Prime')
```

But if x==2, I receive 'Not prime' and if x==333, I get 'Prime'

Comment: You're returning from both `if` and `else` on the first iteration. It's not checking all the divisors, just `2`.

Comment: To expand on Barmar's comment, by returning on the first iteration, the `for` loop never enters the second (and subsequent ) iterations.

Comment: in short: remove the `else` statement and put the `return "Prime"` at the end of the function (outside the `for` loop).